# existing app (java/eclipse/android) to other platform

Tags: java, android, ios, iphone, eclipse

I wrote an application for android (order information, order details, booking timestamps with webservice and webdav) on eclipse.

Is my code reusable for other platforms (e.g. ios, windows phone)?

Thank you for helping me.
michael

Comment: If you use native libraries, no. But there are cross-platform frameworks that you can use, e.g. Cordova, Unity, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You native Android code is not re-usable. But, if you also wrote Webservices (As I understood), you can consume them from other platforms considering they are interoperable (SOAP, REST with JSON/XML, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, nope not. If you had use cross platform tools like phone-gap etc, where you program in java script, then it becomes portable..

Answer (score 0):

if you develop app with native SDK your code is not reusable on another platform but it will be helpful to you to get logic and all flow details from the existing code.

Answer (score 0):

You have developed your application using java, the native code can't be used for other platforms such as iOS or windows as they have there own native languages which they use for development. You can use your web services code for all platforms if it's based on `REST`, `JSON/XML`.